# Speed up SQL to dictionary in python

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, dictionary

How can I speed up the creation of a dictionary form SQL query:
After running a django query on which connects few tables which are one to many I get a lot of repeated data which I want to transform in a nice json format.

```
[
   {'id':1, 'version':1, 'key3':'something different'},
   {'id':1, 'version':1, 'key3':'something different'},
   {'id':1, 'version':1, 'key3':'something different'},
   {'id':2, 'version':1, 'key3':'something different'},
   {'id':2, 'version':1, 'key3':'something different'},
   {'id':3, 'version':1, 'key3':'something different'},
]
```

I wanna build it to look like so:

```
{
    '1':{
        'version':1,
        'key':['something different', 'something different', 'something different']
    },
    '2':{
        'version':1,
        'key':['something different', 'something different']
    },
    '3':{
       'version':1,
       'key':['something different']
    }
}
```

The function I have right now takes about `1s` for about `2000` formatted records, from about `8000` SQL records.
My function is something like

```
def func(data):
    new_dict = {}
    for d in data:
        id = d['id']
        if id not in new_dict:
            new_dict[id]['version'] = d['version']
            new_dict[id]['key'] = []
        new_dict[id]['key'].append(d['key'])
    return new_dict
```

Resulting dictionary does not need to be exact match the one I designed, I can modify displaying function to match dictionary.

Comment: Are you sure it's not your database query that's taking the majority of the time?

Comment: Yes, database is taking like `.01s`

Comment: This should not be taking a long time unless your dataset being returned is extremely large (each dictionary containing many, many items). Your code looks pretty optimal to me. However, if it truly is the problem, them maybe try breaking your queries into multiple then using them as lookups/maps?